# (ASP Web Forms) Dynamically add controls while keeping info after postback?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Let's say I have a bunch of controls that I want to "repeat" on the page. The user can click "Add" to add another set of controls.

I still want the input to be kept (that the user has put in) after the postback that will be triggered when the user clicks "Add".

What is the best way to do this? I would like to use a repeater but then you have to (as far as I know) store the information in ViewState and then re-populate all the controls with the old data.

I am using ASP Web Forms.

Se picture for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpmnG.png

Comment: Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Really depends on where the data comes from. But a datagrid, or a listview, or even a repeater would be better - especially if this data comes from a database.  Such controls (and even perhaps a formview) are data bound - they wire up the editing and display of data for you. And of course they "repeat", and better yet they have viewstate automatic for you. So, little reason to write looping code, or code to inject html when you have a whole truckload of data bound objects that will do all the dirty work for you - and in most cases with VERY little code has to be written.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Yes, I want to use a repeater but because the Click event triggers after Load I have to rebind the data and everything that was restored by viewstate is lost.

Comment: You only load up the data aware item in the page on-load, but you test if postback = false and thus that data binding will only ever run one time on first page load. The control(s) in question will thus preserve their view state.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I already have it that way. I need to rebind the datasource in the Click event/method - otherwise nothing will happen with the repeater. When I rebind the new item appear but everything in the controls are wiped.